# Ruby on Rails 7 - js.erb file not running

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-7

I'm currently having an issue of my "like.js.erb" file not running. I can see that the GET request is successful and the response is the code, but the js.erb code is not running. I put a simple "console.log("hello")" which is not running either. Any help would be greatly appreciated

**/controllers/likes_controller.rb**

```
class LikesController < ApplicationController
    before_action :authenticate_account!
    protect_from_forgery except: :save_like
    
    def save_like
        @like = Like.new(post_id: params[:post_id], account_id: current_account.id)
        @post_id = params[:post_id]

        respond_to do |format|
            format.js{
                if @like.save
                    @success = true
                else
                    @success = false
                end

                render "posts/like"
            }
        end
    end
end
```

**likes_controller.js**

```
import { Controller } from "@hotwired/stimulus"

export default class extends Controller {
  connect() {
    this.element.addEventListener("click", function(e){
        var post_id = e.target.getAttribute("data-id")
        console.log(post_id)
       
        var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
        oReq.open("GET", "/post/like/" + post_id)
        oReq.send()
    })
  }
}
```

**/views/posts/like.js.erb**

```
console.log("hello")
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this issue as well on my upgrade.

My fix was changing the form declaration from:

```
<%= form_with url: sign_in_path do |f| %>
```

to

```
<%= form_with url: sign_in_path, local: false do |f| %>
```

Setting 'local: false' sets the form request in as 'JS'.

Comment: How would I be able to implement this in a non form element? The javascript that I'm trying to run is being triggered by an HTML element

Comment: How to use it with link_to tag for JS request?

Answer (score 1):

If anyone else is struggling with this situation, from what I read js.erb files have been deprecated in Rails 7 due to security concerns. Rails 7 also uses import_maps rather than webpack so all javascript files should be ran from app/javascript/controllers. I ended up just removing my js.erb file and moving its contents to my javascript/controllers and it's working fine now.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PtxZvFnL2i0&ab_channel=DavidHeinemeierHansson

This video helped me understand how to run javascript in Ruby On Rails 7 Applications.

Comment: `create.js.erb` is called automatically by rails after the create action. You moved its contents to `javascript/controllers`, but how do you achieve the automatic invocation of that particular code?

Comment: First, "Deprecated" means to be removed but still supported for the time being. So if `js.erb` files were deprecated they would still work in Rails 7 (which they do). Second, I can't find any source saying `js.erb` files are, in fact, deprecated and to be removed. If you have one it should be cited because this does not appear to be the case. Also, Rails 7 does not always use import_maps over Webpack. Both are supported and it's configurable which to use.